# Get mysql table field names in ZF2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I want to store the csv data dynamically into mysql table.    According to my csv columns header i want to insert the data into respective columns in mysql table. For this, I need to get all the table fields name from Zend Framework Controller or Model.

I have tried with:

**

```
$metadata = new Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata($adapter);
$table = $metadata->getTable($tableName);
$table->getColumns();
```

**

But, it shows the error:

**Fatal error: Class 'Import\Model\Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata' not found.**

How can I get all the mysql table fields name using **Zend Framework 2**?

Comment: Remember namespaces ... `$metadata = new \Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata($dba)`. You're missing the leading backslash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use a backslash before zend
correct one :

```
$metadata = new \Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata($adapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `use`-statement at the top of your file.

```
namespace Import\Model;

use Zend;
```

Or you use the following:

```
namespace Import\Model;

use Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata;

// ... lots of code here ;-)
$metadata = new Metadata($adapter);
```

Comment: Things are more helpful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**At Header section**

namespace Import\Model;

use Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata;

**In Modal function**

$metadata = new Metadata($adapter);

$fields=$metadata->getColumnNames($table);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new instance of Metadata (its depricated), you should use the factory for this

```
use Zend\Db\Metadata\Source\Factory;

$metadata = Factory::createSourceFromAdapter($adapter);
```